# My app crashes when I clicked the Imagebutton instead of taking me to another Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm making an android app on Android Studio. And I come out with a problem . When I click my ImageButton the app crashes instead of going to a new activity (Slide1)...
I dont know where I got it wrong .

Here is my MainActivity.java

```java
package android.example.ptreinas;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton imageButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
               openSlide1();
            }
        });
        }
        public void openSlide1(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Slide1.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

and my activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/red">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/gym" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Programa de treinos "
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="80px"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Escolha o programa de treino mais adequado aos seus objetivos."
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50px"
        android:textSize="50px"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_right"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:padding="50px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="150px"

         />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.example.ptreinas">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I dont know if you need the second activity (slide1.xml , Slide1.java) let me know

I need your help, thanks in advance .

Comment: did you added your activity in manifest?, please add the exception as well.

Comment: please  post your manifest file

Comment: I added the manifest file , above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Slide1.class);
```

by this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Slide1.class);
```

Comment: Tried, still the same . App closes soon as I click the ImageButton

Comment: then can you copy/past your crash log messages here please ?

Comment: I replied the log crash message

Comment: yes, in this case you have to check two things : did you create **Slide1 activity**? if yes , then **check your Manifest.xml file: did you registred your Slide1 activity in manifest ?**

Comment: to register an activity in your manifest you should add <activity android:name="your.package.Slide1" ></activity>

Answer (score 0):

add your second activity in manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android.example.ptreinas">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
//add this line
<activity android:name=".Slide1"/>
</application>
```